# running command in background in subprocesss and capturing the logs

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, background-process, nohup

I am running a command is background using nohup in subprocess python using below command, but I am not able to redirect the logs to a different file instead of nohup.out.

When below command is ran from shell it tis working fine and redirecting the logs, but when ran from python subprocess it is not creating those log files

`nohup /usr/bin/spark-submit --class com.gdl.app.TestSparkStreamingSleep --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true gdl-spark-spd-1.0.jar sandbox > logs/sparkdetailed_SPD_TestSparkStreamingSleep_20220318_115937.log.out 2> logs/sparkdetailed_SPD_TestSparkStreamingSleep_20220318_115937.log.err < /dev/null &`

python subprocess code

```
cmd = "nohup /usr/bin/spark-submit --class com.gdl.app.TestSparkStreamingSleep --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true gdl-spark-spd-1.0.jar sandbox > logs/sparkdetailed_SPD_TestSparkStreamingSleep_20220318_115937.log.out 2> logs/sparkdetailed_SPD_TestSparkStreamingSleep_20220318_115937.log.err < /dev/null &"
res = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
pid = os.getpgid(res.pid)
logger.info("Process ID : {}".format(pid))
```

Note: I have tried below

- converting the command into a list like

`['nohup', '/usr/bin/spark-submit', '--class', 'com.gdl.app.TestSparkStreamingSleep', '--master', 'yarn', '--deploy-mode', 'client', '--conf', 'spark.eventLog.enabled=true', 'gdl-spark-spd-1.0.jar', 'sandme', '>', 'logs/sparkdetailed_SPD_TestSparkStreamingSleep_20220318_111813.log', '2>&1', '&']`

- I have tired `nohup cmd > mylog.log 2>&1 &`
- I have also tried `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` in subprocess, I know it wont help but tried this one aswell.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be using nohup here, _or_ trying to background your subprocess explicitly, unless you have a very good explanation of why you need to do those things. _Do_ you have such an explanation?

Comment: Beyond that, `>file`, `2>&1`, `&`, etc. aren't command-line arguments at all; they're _shell directives_. They only work if you have a shell. `subprocess` provides different ways to accomplish all those things (`stdout=open('file', 'w')` instead of `>file`, f/e; or `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` instead of `2>&1`)

Comment: Anyhow -- if you _do_ background something properly, having it write to disk instead of to a FIFO, then the only way you can capture its output is with a `tail` analogue. Plenty of those exist for Python -- but again, you probably _shouldn't_ be trying to background your process at all; when you background it, you prevent Python from knowing if and when it exits, what its exit status was, etc.

Comment: (and if you _really_ care about making the process outlive the Python program that started it, then you're better off getting rid of nohup and starting it as a transient systemd service or whatever your local operating system's equivalent is; read the manual to [`systemd-run`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html)).

Comment: One thing to remember: `nohup` isn't magic. It isn't even very useful in shell. Run the function definition `my_nohup() { [ -t 0 ] && exec </dev/null; if [ -t 1 ] && [ -t 2 ]; then exec >nohup.out 2>&1; elif [ -t 1 ]; then exec >nohup.out; elif [ -t 2 ]; then exec 2>nohup.out; fi; "$@" & disown -h "$!"; }` and you have a command `my_nohup` that's a slightly better `nohup` than the original (because it does the backgrounding part automatically, which the original doesn't).

Comment: Anyhow, the python equivalent to `foo &` is just `p = subprocess.Popen(['foo'])`, as opposed to `p = subprocess.call(['foo'])`. Unless you want to not just background but _daemonize_, that's all you need.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry for the delayed response, I want this the be running in background, and I don't want to capture the exit code of the command, because this is a long running job and we have other programs or ways to get the status of the application.

Comment: All "in the background" means to a shell is that it doesn't implicitly `wait()` on a process to finish before going on to the next command. Using `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.run()` gives you that already.

Comment: ...if you intend "in the background" to mean something different/additional here, you'll need to spell out exactly what that is.

Comment: You can test this trivially yourself. Run `python3 -c 'import subprocess, shutil; subprocess.Popen([shutil.which("sleep"), "600"])'`, and you'll see that there's a copy of `sleep 600` left running after your Python program exited.